# edit meta field with WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

this is my first post so I apologize if I do wrong. I am currently working on a website of my own in which I am trying to update, create and delete property type entries. I can perform almost everything without problem but I am unable to edit the property_meta field.

This is the command that I think I should edit the field, as other fields that are not metadata do work:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://myweb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/properties/18493' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvY2hvbGxvY2l0eS5lcyIsImlhdCI6MTY1NTkwNTg5MSwibmJmIjoxNjU1OTA1ODkxLCJleHAiOjE2NTY1MTA2OTEsImRhdGEiOnsidXNlciI6eyJpZCI6IjIifX19.J6-R8LQslxWINaSR6alTAQEkxQrDCykx0ZkfSSsjOSU' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "property_meta": {
            "fave_property_price": [
                "33"
            ]
    }
}'
```

[Image of the key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hhll.png)

The call with postman returns 200, but I can't get the value to change. Thanks for your help

I have managed to find out that the php code that displays this metadata in the REST API is the following:

```
 /*------------------------------------------------
 * Properties Meta Fields for rest API
 *----------------------------------------------- */
if( !function_exists('houzez_property_rest_api_field')) {
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'houzez_property_rest_api_field' );

    function houzez_property_rest_api_field() {
        register_rest_field( 'property', 'property_meta', array(
            'get_callback' => 'houzez_get_rest_api_property_meta'
        ) );
    }

    function houzez_get_rest_api_property_meta( $object ) {
        $post_id = $object['id'];
        $property_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );

        // add filter
        $property_meta = apply_filters( 'houzez_property_rest_api_meta', $property_meta );

        // return meta
        return $property_meta;
    }
}
```

But I still can't edit them via API REST

Comment: Is that your actual authentication token?

Comment: sorry i put a dummy url

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced Custom Fields plugin has given me life, simply adding a filter of the field I want to modify or create with the API works.

[image: 1]